# iPython: Could not install notebook. Please install ipython-notebook

Tags: python, linux, ipython, jupyter-notebook

So I successfully installed iPython on Linux and I am trying to install the notebook feature from the console and it says I already have it:

```
$ pip install ipython[ipython-notebook]
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython[ipython_notebook] in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Installing extra requirements: 'ipython_notebook'
Cleaning up...
```

I tried upgrading but I got this:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 257, in run
    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 172, in from_line
    return cls(req, comes_from, url=url, prereleases=prereleases)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 70, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2667, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2605, in parse_requirements
    line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2573, in scan_list
    raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'ipython[ipython-notebook]--upgrade', 'at', '--upgrade')
Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpn3u5qv
```

So I tried running it regardless and that's what I get:

```
$ ipython notebook
Could not start notebook. Please install ipython-notebook
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the debug file at ´/tmp/tmpn3u5qv´? Are there further information in there? And are you sure that is the way pip works? As far as I the syntax is `pip install package[dependencies]`, but you used it the other way round...

Comment: I think you meant `pip install ipython[notebook]`. Alternatively, you can install it with `apt-get install ipython-notebook`, though that might get you an older version.

Answer (score 5):

`pip install --upgrade ipython[notebook]`

Fixed my problem. For some reason `--upgrade` fixed some dependency.